# Change date "format" when gleened from .getValue in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I know that the date object you get when using something like

```
`var ADateFrommyspreadsheet = Sheet.getRange('J1').getValue();
```

does not have a "format", but when I use that value to replace text in a document thusly:

```
`copyBody.replaceText('keyTodaysDate', TodaysDate);
```

It works replaces the text with Wed Jul 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
I just want it to read either Wed Jul 03 2013, or 7/3/2013 or some other "format".
Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Utilities service to return a date formatted as required.

```
var TodaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(ADateFrommySpreadsheet, "GMT", ""EEE MMM dd yyyy");
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)